# swift optional unexpected error

Tags: class, swift, option-type

I'm new here. I'm puzzled with an error. This swift code causes an error that I cannot understand. It merely comes from the Apple documentation "Optional Chaining as an Alternative to Forced Unwrapping"

```
class Person {
    var residence: Residence?
}
class Residence {
    var numberOfRooms = 1
}

let john = Person()
john.residence = Residence()
john.residence.numberOfRooms = 5
```

// error here : 'Residence?' does not have a member named 'numberOfRooms'

Answer (score 4):

The `residence` property of `Person` is an optional, so in order to access to its content you have to unwrap it. You can use optional chaining to do that:

```
john.residence?.numberOfRooms = 5
              ^
```

That means: if residence is not nil, continue evaluating what's at the right side of the expression, otherwise cancel.

The error seems a nonsense, because `Residence` does have a property named `numberOfRooms`. The point is that `john.residence` is an optional type, and optionals are instances of an enum, `Optional<T>` - which  doesn't have a `numberOfRooms` property. Using optional chaining the `Residence` instance is unwrapped from the enum (i.e. the optional), and so the error disappears because `Residence` has that property.

More info at [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-XID_368) (note this is the documentation mentioned in the question)